# Keyboard layout switching key combinations

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

Currently my keyboard layout switches sometimes between Querty and Azerty Period. But I don't know which key combination initiates the switching.

I disabled all short keys as can be seen in the image below. It is still possible to switch via `Windows key` + `Space`, but that is not a combination I use by accident.

Are there some other key combinations? And if so, how to disable them?

I have a Windows 8.1.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by ArcSoft TotalMedia 3.5 (PVR program) and a digital TV USB tuner resetting the keyboard layout (when the program is not capable of getting a decent signal due to for instance a bad connection between the USB tuner and the antenna).

Answer (score 0):

> Are there some other key combinations?

There is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

But according to your screenshot, it should be disabled: *Schakelen tussen invoertalen = (Geen)*.